# Sending a canned response with Gmail Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I'm writing an auto-replying tool for gmail using Google Apps Script (http://script.google.com).

[In the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/), I don't find any function to send a Gmail *canned response*. **Is there no such feature?**

If not, how would you handle this? I thought about sending an email to myself in gmail:

```
To:example@gmail.com
From:example@gmail.com
Subject:This is a canned response ID1847
Hi
This is a test
```

adding the label `mycannedresponse` to it, and then loading in Apps Script this mail from code:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("label:mycannedresponse ID1847");
if (threads.length != 1) { 
    // error: the canned response ID... is not unique
} else {
    threads[0].getBody(...)
    threads[0].getPlainBody(...)
}
```

**Is there a more-documented way to do it?**

Comment: Not very surprising: there are many features available through the interface that Apps Script doesn't have methods for. I'd either hardcode canned responses or store them in some spreadsheet for ease of editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the sendEmail method for GAS? You can create a trigger to fire off this email.

```
 // The code below will send an email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
GmailApp.sendEmail("mike@example.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString());
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body